# Send HTTPS post request via nodejs

Tags: node.js, post, https

Edit: *Code is typescript, but very similar to JS, so I hope thats not a problem ;)*

I try to make an HTTPS request but only getting "read ECONNRESET" after some timeout in the error event.

To encode post data I use `require('querystring');` and it works fine, data is exactly what the browser sends.

```
var postData = querystring.stringify(data);

var postOptions = {
    host: 'my.host.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/openid/loginsubmit',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referer':' https://my.host.com/openid/login',
        'Content-Length': postData.length // 157 in web
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
```

I took all the headers I tracked with Fiddler to be sure there is no reason to reject my request on serverside.

Then I start try to send the request using:

```
var resString = '';
var postReq:any = https.request(postOptions, (httpRes:any) => {
    console.log("statusCode: ", httpRes.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", httpRes.headers);

    httpRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
        resString += chunk;
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    });
    httpRes.on('end', function () {
        res.send(resString);
    });
});

postReq.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('ERROR failed to login into website');
    res.send(err.message);
});

postReq.write(postData); // even tried to add 'utf8' as second parameter
postReq.end();
```

Now all I get is an error after some timeout with the message `read ECONNRESET`

If one could help me with an example (maybe on some arbitrary https host) where an https post request works it would help much.

Or are there some misstakes in it? Maybe I have to provide some server cert somewhere to encrypt my post data?

Comment: It should be `Buffer.byteLength(postData)`, not `postData.length`. That might cause issues depending on what you are sending.

Comment: the value is correct, checked it with the value captured by fiddler. I send only chars. But I will test it to be sure.

Comment: Not sure then, sorry. FYI `postData.length` will be wrong if you send any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: My current guess is, that I'm missing a cookie, any idea how to attack one to my request?

Comment: Cookies send as headers, so you would put it in with all of the other headers.